# rerwrite url in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to make the old urls point to the new pages. I'm having trouble because the old URL looks like this: http://nilandsplace.com/store/camping_eng/coghlans-campfire-cooking-forks-toaster-forks-package-of-4.html.
I want to do a URL re-right in .ht access from mywebsite.com/camping_eng/some.html to mywebsite.com/camping/some.html, were the "some.html" part is identical. 
Only camping_eng changes to camping.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /store
RewriteRule ^camping_eng/(.*)$ camping/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer,but I still get an 404 not found

Comment: Hm, I guess because of the RewriteBase I added. Your question is contradictory here, sorry. First you have that 'store' in the urls, then later it is missing. So it might be you have to adjust my answer a little. In the end you will have to _understand_ what you are doing. You cannot just copy something and expect it to work. Then it would be better not to run a site on the internet, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Well every one has to learn some way. I first went to the Apache website but I didn't get the question right and was getting nothing  I got it to work with:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /store
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/camping_eng
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ camping/$1 [L,R=301]
But I think I am rewriting everything without the condition

Comment: Indeed you do not need that condition, since all requests _not_ containing that token should not be rewritten...

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? Or the server configuration?

Comment: Thanks for your help I need a good website to look the stuff up, so far I have found examples with little explanation as to what the symbols mean

Comment: I am not an administrator but I fake it by the good grace of others. I am running centos on my VPN

Comment: You have access to irc? ping me on channel #arkascha :-)

Comment: I suppose Ubuntu has IRC but I have not installed or found it yet. I had IRC on widows but I gave up after xp for anything important. Looks like I have a lot of choices for Linux

Comment: Take a look at the applications `konversation` or `pidgin`, depending on which desktop you use, KDE4 or Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^camping_eng/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]+)/?$ http://mywebsite.com/camping/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This example works according to your question:

from `mywebsite.com/camping_eng/some.html`

to `mywebsite.com/camping/some.html`  were the "some.html" part is identical.